# windows routing.. - default gateway vs static route

Tags: windows, networking

In my window server machine, I have 2 network card in which 1 has a default gateway and another doesn't

Network card 1 - 172.16.**65**.241 - gateway 172.16.65.254

Network card 2 - 172.16.**66**.241 - no default gateway

Added a static route to 172.16.3.0/24 to use network card 2.

> route -p add 172.16.3.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.16.**66**.254 if 17

Traffic to 172.16.3.0 was going out of network card2 to gateway 172.16.66.254.

Everything works fine until out of a sudden until traffic to 172.16.3.0 started to go via network card 1 with default gateway/route.

What could have cause the switch of traffic from network card 2 to network card 1?

After a reboot, traffic to 172.16.3.0 resume back to use network card 2 again.

```
=========================================================================== 接口列表
 12...00 0c 29 dc 40 42 ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
 17...00 0c 29 dc 40 4c ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 路由表
===========================================================================
活动路由: 网络目标        网络掩码          网关       接口   跃点数
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    172.16.65.254    172.16.65.241    266
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0            在链路上         127.0.0.1    306
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255            在链路上         127.0.0.1    306
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上         127.0.0.1    306
           172.16.3.0    255.255.255.0    172.16.66.254    172.16.66.241     11
          172.16.65.0    255.255.255.0            在链路上     172.16.65.241    266
        172.16.65.241  255.255.255.255            在链路上     172.16.65.241    266
        172.16.65.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上     172.16.65.241    266
        172.16.66.128  255.255.255.128            在链路上     172.16.66.241    266
        172.16.66.241  255.255.255.255            在链路上     172.16.66.241    266
        172.16.66.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上     172.16.66.241    266
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上     172.16.65.241    266
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上     172.16.66.241    266
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上         127.0.0.1    306
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上     172.16.65.241    266
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上     172.16.66.241    266
    ===========================================================================
永久路由:   网络地址          网络掩码  网关地址  跃点数
               172.16.3.0    255.255.255.0    172.16.66.254       1
                  0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    172.16.65.254     默认
```

===========================================================================

Answer (score 0):

Deletion of route to specific network (172.16.3.0/24 in your case) might have cause the redirection to default route. What caused the route deletion is another question.

Did by any chance network card 2 loose link at some point? This would drop all of the routes on that interface.